# JSON is appearing as unicode entities in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, django, json, jinja2

I using Jinja2 with webapp2.

Jinja2 encodes all 'context' data into unicode as their doc says. This is proving problematic when I try to insert a json string into the the template:

```
jsonData = json.loads(get_the_file('catsJson.txt'))
```

I pass jsonData to template and I'm able to loop it successfully but when I insert a json element into HTML, it looks like this:

```
<option value='[u&#39;dogs&#39;, u&#39;cats&#39;]'>
```

I want it to look like this (as it is in the original json string):

```
<option value='["dogs", "cats"]'>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

You must filter the value through the `safe` filter to tell jinja2 that it shouldn't apply any other filters to the output. In jinja2 syntax this would be:

```
{{ jsonData | safe }}
```

Note that since you are calling `json.loads` you actually do not have json data anymore, you have a python list object. Thus when it is serialized it's the same as calling `unicode(['dogs', 'cats'])` which is going to give you your `u` prefix. You might not want to actually parse the json data, or you'll need to turn the list into a string manually instead of having jinja2 do it for you.

Comment: now it outputs: `[u'dogs', u'cats']`

How do I remove the u prefix?

Comment: Convert the array elements to `str`: `map(str, jsonData)`

Comment: answer updated, you're letting jinja2 turn a python list into a string, so it ends up using the string representation of a list.

Comment: @Xion
but I need to iterate jsonData in the template

Comment: @MichaelMerickel
Is there a way to turn a list into string within Jinja2?

Comment: You can get away with some python in jinja2, but not much. Assuming `item` is a list, you could do `{{ ', '.join(item) }}`. The other 2 options are to iterate over the list using a jinja2 `joiner` object, or to convert the lists to strings from within python and expose that new "renderable" object to your template.

Comment: for now I'll just do `','.join(item)` and then split them to recreate the list in jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel Thanks man, after doing one day R&D your answer save me.

Answer (score 1):

In Jinja 2.9 I followed @Xion's advice to first convert the iterable elements to string using `map('string')`. The map filter result I then converted to a list which is finally output as JSON using the `tojson` built-in filter.

```
{{ jsonData|map('string')|list|tojson }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to act on the array in the Jinja side, but just need to pass the packet to javascript, I would recommend using:

```
json.dumps(python_object_or_array)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

This stringified variable, when passed into jinja gets passed down to javascript without getting the pythonic unicode markings on variables.  And incidentally, will likely fix `True` and `False` getting fixed to `true` and `false` as javascript would expect.

So in the context of flask, it would look something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
     if userNeedsToLogin():
          session['routePath'] = request.full_path
          return render_template('login.html', error=None)
     else:
          return render_home()

def render_home():
     print "Rendering Home"
     results = get_some_database_query_results()
     data_out = json.dumps(results)
     return render_template('home.html', data=data_out)
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- import javascript function processData -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- page of stuff -->
  <script>
     processData( {{ data|safe }} );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```