# Flask: rendering unicode characters in template

Tags: python, unicode, flask

In a Flask app I'm working on, I need to display Unicode text to users. When testing them out in the Python shell, my functions seem to work fine:

```
>>> sr = rym_scraper.get_artist_info('sigur ros')
>>> print sr.name # a string encoded using str.encode('utf8')
Sigur Rós
```

When I actually test it out in the app, I get this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

With the final exception being in the template it produces this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/eric/projects/whatshouldilistento/app/app.py", line 29, in enter_band
    return band_info(form.name.data)
  File "/Users/eric/projects/whatshouldilistento/app/app.py", line 45, in band_info
    return render_template('band_info.html')
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 125, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 107, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/eric/Envs/whatshouldilistento/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/eric/projects/whatshouldilistento/app/templates/band_info.html", line 9, in top-level template code
    <div>{{ message }}</div>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I display the Unicode string in my rendered template?

Comment: try `{{ message.decode('utf-8') }}`

Comment: @Lafada -- That works, not sure why I didn't think of it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Post answer, please select it so other will get correct answer when they come to your post :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your message is non-ascii, you have to decode it and convert it to `unicode`.

your can convert it using.

```
{{ message.decode('utf-8') }}
```

Comment: it means I need to write this every time I display message??

Comment: If you have to decode in `utf-8` then you have to write every time

Comment: Old but still useful for me today

Answer (score 9):

add below to your start up file

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

this works for me

Comment: this method works perfect for me. I have tried many other methods, but do not works. Thank you so much

Comment: Works fine but I don't understand what the "reload" call accomplishes. I would think that reloading a module right after importing it should be a no-op. Also, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) specifically advises against reloading sys:

Answer (score 1):

My unicode strings were embedded in arrays and objects, and I passed them using `json.dumps()` to get rid of the unicode references.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50612950/999943