# Ansible template adds 'u' to array in template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have the following `vars` inside of my ansible playbook I got the following structure

```
domains:
  - { main: 'local1.com', sans: ['test.local1.com', 'test2.local.com'] }
  - { main: 'local3.com' }
  - { main: 'local4.com' }
```

And have the following inside of the my `conf.j2`

```
{% for domain in domains %}
  [[acme.domains]]

    {% for key, value in domain.iteritems() %}
      {% if value is string %}
        {{ key }} = "{{ value }}"
      {% else %}
        {{ key }} = {{ value }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now when I go in the VM and see the file I get the following:

**Output**

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local1.com
  sans = [u'test.local1.com', u'test2.local.com']
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local3.com"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local4.com"
```

Notice the **u** inside of the `sans` array.

**Excpeted output**

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local1.com"
  sans = ["test.local1.com", "test2.local.com"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local3.com"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local4.com"
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I ended up dumping the variable to json, and it fixed it (for jinja2).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50612950/999943

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You get `u' '` because you print the object containing the Unicode strings and this is how Python renders it by default.

You can filter it with `list | join` filters:

```
{% for domain in domains %}
[[acme.domains]]
{% for key, value in domain.iteritems() %}
{% if value is string %}
  {{ key }} = "{{ value }}"
{% else %}
  {{ key }} = ["{{ value | list | join ('\',\'') }}"]
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can rely on the fact, that the string output after `sans =` is a JSON and render it with `to_json` filter:

```
{{ key }} = {{ value | to_json }}
```

Either will get you:

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local1.com"
  sans = ["test.local1.com", "test2.local.com"]
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local3.com"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "local4.com"
```

But the first one is more versatile.

Comment: Heads up: Actually it's tojson and not to_json. See: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tojson

Comment: Ansible provides [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) and that's what I meant to use.